# How Can I make sure I applied the correct code format in intelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have both Java and Scale code in the project. Editing 2 types of code in one task is common. I inputted the **google-java-code-style schema** for Java code format and installed the **scalafmt plugin** in the intellij IDEA.

Both of them use **Ctrl+Shift+L** to reformat the code. How can I make sure the correct one has been called when I press those hot keys. I feel all the code were formatted by the google-java-code-style schema for the moment.

Is there any indicators could inform me which schema or plugin is triggered for the reformatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the shortcuts from..

1. From the main menu, choose File | Settings on Windows and Linux or JetBrains Rider | Preferences on macOS, then choose Keymap on the left.
2. Select one of the pre-configured Keymaps, which you want to use as the base for the new one, and click Copy. Accept the default name, or change it as required.

Comment: do you know how can I create a map key for google-java-format plugin in Intellij IDEA? I didn't found any predefined mapping key for that plugin.

Comment: i dont know what exactly you are trying to do but find the below link may help you..   https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-intellij.html

Comment: in the above link look for the section google-java-format plugin